# Need To Factory Restore Laptop. How Do I Backup and Restore Thunderbird?

Tags: email, backup, restore

I need to do a factory restore on my Medion Vista Laptop.
How can I back up and restore my desktop items including,
and especially, Thunderbird email clients and folders.
It receives the emails from my ISP.
Also on the desktop is my Events Planner, Spam Protection Programme,
Panda Antivirus, Revo Uninstaller, etc.
I will need to download Firefox again, but I believe that I can sync that.
Thanks.

Comment: What did your research tell you? Did you search for "How Do I Backup and Restore Thunderbird?"

Comment: Everything you need should be in the profile(s) you use. Where this is located depends on your operating system, and can be found in Help -> Troubleshooting: back up the directory one level _above_ this to save all your profiles. The profile(s) will also hold your add-ons, but not plug-ins. The same considerations apply to Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Thunderbird profile information is located in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird` and `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Thunderbird`.

To restore your Thunderbird profile, simply copy these folders to the new installation before starting Thunderbird for the first time. (If you've already started Thunderbird, delete the new profile and replace it with your existing profile.) Thunderbird will load up the existing profile and all your emails and other data will be there.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, be sure to click on the check mark below the voting controls so that we know the question has been successfully answered. Thanks.